# How to prevent dynamic button's onclick event triggering on render?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have jQuery script which dynamically adds buttons with `onclick()` event. `Onclick()` event is simply calling some other JavaScript function. jQuery works perfectly in that it creates buttons dynamically, but **`onclick()` event triggers without clicking**. I put debugging alert in `someFunction` and seeing it `number_of_created_buttons` times which means that `onclick` event triggering on render. How to prevent such strange behavior? I want `onClick` event to only fire when user presses the button.

My script is the following:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#getXmlFiles').click(function() {
            $.get('/getUserDocs', function(responseJson) {
                $("#docsDiv").empty();
                var $table = $('<table>').appendTo($('#docsDiv')).width('100%');
                $.each(responseJson, function(index, item){
                    var $btn = $('<button/>',
                    {
                        text: 'Action',
                        style:'width:100%',
                        click: someFunction(item)
                    });

                    $('<tr>').appendTo($table)
                        .append($('<td>').text(item))
                        .append($('<td>').append($btn));

                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you produce the problem here http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `click` to this one:

```
click: function () {
    someFunction(item);
}
```

---

This is because you are invoking `someFunction` immediately on the `click`. You must set a callback for it. Just like above.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because you are calling the function when you actually just want to assign it as an event handler. Try this code and see if that helps:

```
var $btn = $('<button/>',
{
    text: 'Action',
    style:'width:100%',
    click: someFunction  // note the missing brackets
});
```

Comment: What about the `item` parameter which should pass to the `someFunction`?

Comment: @Rox, I also mentioned parameter passing problem, good catch)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can avoid attaching the event handler to the each of the buttons event, rather just add a class to the buttons and write a delegated event handler by attaching it to the same class like this way

**jQuery code:**

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#getXmlFiles').click(function() {
             $.get('/getUserDocs', function(responseJson) {
            $("#docsDiv").empty();
            var $table = $('<table>').appendTo($('#docsDiv')).width('100%');
            $.each(responseJson, function(index, item){
                var $btn = $('<button/>',
                {
                    text: 'Action',
                    style:'width:100%',
                    //click: someFunction(item)
                    class:'trg'
                });

                $('<tr>').appendTo($table)
                        .append($('<td>').text(item))
                        .append($('<td>').append($btn));

            });
            });
        });

        $(document).on('click','.trg',function(){
             //code to handle click event for all dynamic buttons here
        });
    });
```

This way the click event won't be called until triggered manually also the code looks neat.